# Regarding concurrent hashMap segmentation and indidivual locking

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I was exploring the concurrenthashMap API and  found `static final int` `DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 16;` which states that map will be divided in 16 parts internally, Now my query is that as we know that in case of concurrent hashMap the whole map object is not locked and instead a lock is made on a portion of the Map.

Can somebody show in a small picture representation that how map is divided and and how it internally broke by segmentation and how each thread guards the piece of it segment , Please advise with a small graphical picture that will be more helpful.

Comment: check this [link](http://javarticles.com/2012/06/concurrenthashmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

A ConcurrentHashMap has an array of 'segments', where each segment is a completely independent hash table that is protected by its own mutex.  The calling thread computes the hash code (32 bits) for the given key, and then it uses the top four bits of that to pick which segment to use.

When the thread is doing a put(), it locks the mutex for the segment.  The get() operation is a little trickier because it first tries to get the value *without* locking the mutex.